# Google Places autocomplete does not exist in GoogleMaps SDK

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-maps, gmsautocomplete

I've used `CocoaPods` to import `GoogleMaps` to my project:

```
pods 'GoogleMaps'
```

Then I tried to `import <GoogleMaps/GoogleMaps.h>` and use the `GMSAutocompleteViewController` but it does not exist in the project!

I'm trying to implement the delegate `GMSAutocompleteViewControllerDelegate`, but it is nowhere to be found.

Can someone explain why?

Comment: does the include work at all? does your project have custom frameworks that don't come from Pods?

Comment: This is a good search path. Set in the Pod config generated: FRAMEWORK_SEARCH_PATHS = $(inherited) "${PODS_ROOT}/GoogleMaps/Frameworks"

Answer (score 1):

Well this is somewhat old question but actually i have faced same problem. i have done some research and then i found that version of google SDK was 1.10.3, and in that SDK there was no any controller like **GMSAutocompleteViewController**

so only thing to do update the latest version of google map SDK.

i have tried this **pods 'GoogleMaps'** but it does not update latest version it always update 1.10.3.

then finally i have tried giving version in pod file like this 
  **pod ‘GoogleMaps’ ,‘ ~> 1.13.2’** now problem is solved.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `@import GoogleMaps` instead of `<GoogleMaps/GoogleMaps.h>`, see google's documentation for more instructions

[Google ios map guide](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/start)

hope this helps !

Comment: `Use of '@import' when modules are disabled` I'm using Objective-C not Swift.

Comment: @starlord doesn't matter - this would change the 'content' of a framework

Answer (score 0):

Google updated the maps api and has split into 2.
Add pod 'GooglePlaces' to your pod file and then add

@import GooglePlaces;